# Oracle ALTER DATABASE OPEN

Tags: oracle, connection

Im having some trouble with an oracle database. Every time i try to connect, i get this message.

> ORA-01033: ORACLE initialization or
>   shutdown in progress

I searched the web, and found that the solution is to execute an  `alter database open` command, but what I dont understand is where should i execute if, since I cant connect to the database.

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should connect `AS SYSDBA`:

```
sqlplus "sys/pwd AS SYSDBA"
```

Comment: Quassnoi's answer assumes that you are executing SQL*Plus on the database host.  You may also connect remotely and start up the database if you have a listener running on the database host that accepts SID (not SERVICE_NAME) connections.  Do this by 1) sqlplus /nolog , then 2) connect sys/pwd@your_db as sysdba , followed by 3) alter database open.

It's likely that there was something that either prevented a full shutdown or complete startup and that is really the problem.  You'll have to examine the alert logs to find the cause

Answer (score 0):

An ORA-01033 would also be thrown if the connection attempt were made against a mounted standby database (Oracle Data Guard environment) by a non-sysdba user.  Maybe a database role change (switchover or failover) has occurred since your last connection attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Which OS are you using? The database is still shutting down - check the alert log as to the status of where it is at. Sometimes there are sessions hanging around that need to manually be killed off, there should be an indication of this in the alert log. It also depends how the database was shutdown, NORMAL, TRANSACTIONAL, IMMEDIATE. Even with a SHUTDOWN IMMEDIATE the sessions hanging around may still happen. To find the sessions on UNIX use the 'ps' to list all processes on the server ('ps -eaf' on Solaris) command and 'grep' for the ORACLE_SID name.